# Java script error in ASP.net C# after partial view refreshing

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In my case everything works fine when the page loads for the first time, after that the "DataTable" script doesn't work when refreshing the partial view. The following error is displayed in the console:

[image: Console Error Image]

The third time it starts working again.

Here is my main view code

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Search", "Customers", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "PartialViewId" }, new { id = "frmSearch" })) { <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
  <div class="x_panel">
    <div class="x_title">
      <h2>Search Clients</h2>
      <ul class="nav navbar-right panel_toolbox">
        <li>
          <a class="collapse-link">
            <i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="x_content">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 ">
          <div class="form-group row"> @Html.Label("Customer Id", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3 col-xs-12 col-sm-3" }) <div class="col-sm-9 col-xs-12 col-md-9"> @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Id, "Enter Surname", new { @class = "form-control required", Id = "Id" }) </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 ">
          <div class="form-group row"> @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TaxCode, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3 col-xs-12 col-sm-3" }) <div class="col-sm-9 col-xs-12 col-md-9"> @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.TaxCode, "Enter Name", new { @class = "form-control required", Id = "TaxCode" }) </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 ">
          <div class="form-group row"> @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Customer_SurName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3 col-xs-12 col-sm-3" }) <div class="col-sm-9 col-xs-12 col-md-9"> @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Customer_SurName, "Enter Surname", new { @class = "form-control required", Id = "Customer_SurName" }) </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 ">
          <div class="form-group row"> @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Customer_Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3 col-xs-12 col-sm-3" }) <div class="col-sm-9 col-xs-12 col-md-9"> @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Customer_Name, "Enter Name", new { @class = "form-control required", Id = "Customer_Name" }) </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button id="SearchButton" type="button" class="btn btn-success">Search</button>
  </div>
</div> } <div id="PartialViewId"> @{ Html.RenderPartial("_SearchResults"); } </div>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/toastr.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  //Root Directory for java script Path Configuration
  var rootDir = "@Url.Content("~/")";
  $(document).on('click', '#SearchButton', function() {
    try {
      $('#SearchButton').prop("disabled", true);
      var $form = $("#frmSearch");
      var xModel = $form.serialize();
      var Id = $('#Id').val();
      var TaxCode = $('#TaxCode').val();
      var Customer_SurName = $('#Customer_SurName').val();
      var Customer_Name = $('#Customer_Name').val();
      if (Id == "" && TaxCode == "" && Customer_SurName == "" && Customer_Name == "") {
        $('#SearchButton').prop("disabled", false);
        toastr.error('Please Fill any field to Search');
      } else {
        $.ajax({
          url: rootDir + 'Customers/Search',
          type: 'POST',
          dataType: 'html',
          cache: false,
          async: false,
          data: xModel,
          success: function(data) {
            $('#SearchButton').prop("disabled", false);
            $("#PartialViewId").html(data);
          }
        });
      }
    } catch (err) {
      $('#SearchButton').prop("disabled", false);
      Swal.fire({
        icon: 'error',
        title: 'Oops...',
        text: err.message,
      })
    }
  })
</script>
```

Here is the Partial view

```
@if (Model != null) { <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
  <div class="x_panel">
    <div class="x_title">
      <h2>Search Results</h2>
      <ul class="nav navbar-right panel_toolbox">
        <li>
          <a></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="collapse-link">
            <i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
    <p>
      <a href="@Url.Action(" Create", "Customers" )" class="btn btn-success fa fa-plus"> Create New</a>
    </p>
    <div class="table-responsive"> @if (Model != null) { <table id="example" class="display">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Surname</th>
            <th>Customer Name</th>
            <th>Contact Number</th>
            <th>Date of Birth</th>
            <th>Birth Place</th>
            <th></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody> @foreach (var item in Model.OrderBy(x => x.Id)) { <tr class="even pointer">
            <td>@item.Customer_SurName</td>
            <td>@item.Customer_Name</td>
            <td>@item.Contact_Number</td>
            <td>@item.Date_of_Formated </td>
            <td>@item.Birth_Place</td>
            <td> @Html.ActionLink(" Edit Customer", "Edit", new { id = item.Id }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary pull-right fa fa-pencil", @target = "_blank" }) @Html.ActionLink(" View Tasks", "Details", new { id = item.Id }, new { @class = "btn btn-dark pull-right fa fa-eye", @target = "_blank" }) @Html.ActionLink(" Create Task", "Create", "TaskMains", new { id = MondoData.Models.IdEncrypt.Encrypt(item.Id.ToString()) }, new { @class = "btn btn-success pull-right fa fa-plus" }) </td>
          </tr> } </tbody>
      </table> } </div>
  </div>
</div> } <script type="text/javascript">
  $('#example').DataTable({});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so with regards your refresh search your throwing out the html and then just re-adding back in. I don't think you can just call DataTable at the end of the partial view.

Basically the easiest thing todo here is to replace

```
success: function(data) {
            $('#SearchButton').prop("disabled", false);
            $("#PartialViewId").html(data);
          }
```

with

```
success: function(data) {
            $('#SearchButton').prop("disabled", false);
            $("#PartialViewId").html(data);
  $('#example').DataTable({});
          }
```

Then in the partial view, remove that part of code all together.

In the longer term I would look into the datatables ajax functions such as
Here
https://datatables.net/manual/ajax
and
https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload()

there are options within datatables to handle search and refresh as well - so that could be useful to your development as a developer.